# any performance recommendations for cpp check visual studio plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cppcheck

I have just recently installed cppcheck which had some pretty good recommendations for static analysis of c++ code online. cppcheck is installed properly and I can run it successfully from command line or the gui. I then installed the Visual Studio Plugin v1.1.0 for cppcheck and I am very disappointed with this plugin.

The project I am working on is so large it just seems to hang, although there is no feedback so I can't say if it's doing anything at all, and what appears to be minimal support for troubleshooting. I was hoping that maybe some proficient users could make some recommendations on how to improve the performance.

I have already removed all checks other than Errors, which is not ideal but I am attempting to speed it up by reducing what it needs to do.

I have attempted to add a regular expression to the exclude include files but I cannot be sure it is even working.

I really don't have time to grab the source code and start debugging it.

I would really like to embed this tool inside of visual studio so that all the developers will actually use it. I have also added cppcheck as an external tool into visual studio, but it really is just a poor man’s attempt to do what the plugin really should do, especially since macros have been removed from visual studio so I cant run it automatically on save.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/472065/Poor-Man-s-Visual-Studio-Cppcheck-Integration

I think it will greatly increase the likelyhood that the developers use the tool if cppcheck is set up to run on save, which is a great feature of the plugin, if it would just work.

In the end I would just really like this plugin to work.

Comment: FWIW I came here because of a google search when I wanted to make CppCheck run faster. I've managed to do that by removing the folders it searches (those provided with `-I`). You get less potential issues, but it makes CppCheck run lightning fast. (And I was not using the plugin, not sure if there is a way to do that with the plugin.)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I decided to add the cppcheckgui.exe to my list of external tools in visual studio. It circumvents the plugin but still works easily for my needs.

I have found using cppcheck together with visual studio's built in code analysis has proven to work very successfully. Both focus on different problems in the source code and the usage of both together I believe provides a more complete analysis of my code.